# Postman returns "could not get any response" when hitting localhost laravel api route that I created

Tags: php, laravel, http, postman

I'm just starting out with api's so pardon me if I'm missing something very obvious. I'm using xampp for my localhost and I've made this api route in Laravel `Route::post('/register', 'RegisterController@register');`

the name of my app is forum-api

this is the route that I'm using to hit the api through postman (I suspect that the problem is most likely this route):

http://localhost:8080/forum-api.app/api/register

whenever I send a request I get an error saying "Could not get any response"

Comment: does `http://localhost:8080/forum-api.app/api` is working properly?

Comment: Which laravel version are you using?

Comment: just checked. it's not. so I'm guessing it's not my route, but there's something wrong with the app itself?

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.3

Comment: how about middleware?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. the middleware is the same as the default laravel application. only thing I've changed here is the new route and the new controller that goes along with it

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem; this is what actually happened
I had typed in the url bar `unknownweb.com/api/cars/23/parts/34`
***INSTEAD OF***  `https://unknownweb.com/api/cars/23/parts/34`